# Importing text file in sqlite with two parameters by python

Tags: python, sqlite, text, import

I try to import 5 configuration files (*rubin1.cfg...rubin5.cfg*) into sqlite3 database. Configuration file is obvious list of strings. Every string starts newline. I would import strings of files into sqlite table and insert index of the configuration file at field *FileID*.

```
import sqlite3, codecs
con = sqlite3.connect("ConfigImport.db")
cur = con.cursor() 
n = 0
sql = """\
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
        TblRubin;

        CREATE TABLE TblRubin 
        (StringId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        FileId INTEGER
        String TEXT)
        """
cur.executescript(sql)
while n < 5:
    n = n + 1
    i = 0
    path = r'C:\\t7\\config\\rubi'+ str(n) + '.cfg'
    f = codecs.open(path, "r", encoding='cp1251') 
    str2 = codecs.open(path, "r", encoding='cp1251').readlines()
    print 'File', path, 'opened. Number of strings: ', str(len(str2))
    for line in f:
        cur.execute('insert into tblrubin values (null, ?, ?)', n, [str2[i].rstrip()])
        i = i + 1
    con.commit()               
cur.close()                
con.close()
```

And as a result:

```
File C:\\t7\\config\\rubi1.cfg opened. Number of strings:  6528
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\t7\programs\analysis\ConfigImport.py", line 25, in <module>
    cur.execute('insert into tblrubin values (null, ?, ?)', (n, str2[i].rstrip()))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table tblrubin has 2 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

When I tried to import only one file and script contains with one parameter, like this...:

```
cur.execute('insert into tblrubin2 values (null, ?)', [str2[i].rstrip()])
```

...import insert operation was success.

Can you take a suggestion how to make correct script of importing text file to sqlite db with two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a comma to your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
    ....
    FileId INTEGER , -- HERE
    String TEXT
    ....
```

or you will have no `String` column.